# How do I call an Eloquent function with arguments?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a staff controller and transactions model. In the staff controller, I am fetching staff transactions with other data as below
**StaffController.php**

```
    $transactions = Transaction::thisMerchant()
->earnedByStaff($staff)
  ->where(function ($q) use ($staffID) {
    $q->where('staff_id', $staffID)
      ->orWhere(function ($qq) use ($staffID) {
        $qq
          ->whereNull('staff_id')
          ->whereHas('items', function ($qqq) use ($staffID) {
            $qqq->where('staff_id', $staffID);
          });
      })
      ->orWhereHas('associateCommissions', function ($qq) use ($staffID) {
        $qq->where('staff_id', $staffID);
      });
  })
  ->when($start_date && $end_date, function ($q) use (
    $start_date,
    $end_date
  ) {
    $q->whereBetween(\DB::raw('date(date)'), [
      $start_date . ' 00:00:00',
      $end_date . ' 23:59:59',
    ]);
  })
  ->with('client')
  ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
  ->where('is_void', null)
  ->where('is_draft', null)
  ->with('items.sellable.sellable')
  ->with('associateCommissions')
  ->paginate(10);
```

In the transactions model, I have this
**Transaction.php**

```
  public function earnedFromTransaction($staff_id)
{
$staff = Staff::find($staff_id);
if ($this->is_void == '1') {
  return 0;
}

if ($this->provider() == 'Empty') {
  return 0;
}

if ($this->provider() == 'Split') {
  $amounts = Titem::where('transaction_id', $this->id)
    ->where('staff_id', $staff_id)
    ->whereHas('product', function ($q) {
      $q->whereNull('commission');
    })
    ->whereHas('transaction', function ($q) {
      $q->where('is_void', null);
    })
    ->sum('frozen_staff_commission');

  $discounts = Titem::where('transaction_id', $this->id)
    ->where('staff_id', $staff_id)
    ->whereHas('product', function ($q) {
      $q->whereNull('commission');
    })
    ->whereHas('transaction', function ($q) {
      $q->where('is_void', null);
    })
    ->sum('discount');

  // When the frozen staff rate is zero, just give sellable commission
  $titem_commissions = Titem::where('transaction_id', $this->id)
    ->where('staff_id', $staff_id)
    ->where('frozen_staff_commission', '<=', 0)
    ->whereHas('product', function ($q) {
      $q->whereNotNull('commission');
    })
    ->sum('commission');

  $total =
    floatval($amounts) +
    floatval($titem_commissions) -
    floatval($discounts);

  return $total;
}

return floatval($this->frozen_staff_commission);
  }

  public function earnedByStaff(Staff $staff)
  {
   return StaffCommissionEngine::earnedFromTransaction($this, $staff);
  }
```

I am getting this error `BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::earnedByStaff() in file`

I have tried using `$transactions = Transaction::earnedByStaff($staff)...` but this returns

```
Error: Non-static method App\Transaction::earnedByStaff() cannot be called statically in file
```

How do I call the `earnedByStaff()` method and pass the `$staff` to it?

Answer (score 0):

Make the function 'earnedByStaff' static.

```
public static function earnedByStaff( Staff $staff)
{
   return StaffCommissionEngine::earnedFromTransaction($this, $staff);
}
```

After that it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope method

```
public function scopeEarnedByStaff($query,$arg)
    {
        .....
    }
```

You can also use the call method on the query builder to call a function on the model class

```
 MyModel::where('column', 'value')->get();
     $transactions = Transaction::thisMerchant()
    ->call('earnedByStaff', [$staff])->where()
    ..
    ..
```